# Why won't pygame draw a circle?

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

I am a beginner in python, and I'm trying to draw a circle wherever the mouse is(I also have a mouse and background image). Here is my code:

```
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            color = (100,100,100)
            posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            screen.lock()
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (posx,posy), 50)
            screen.unlock()

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mousec.get_width()/2
    y -= mousec.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mousec, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Whenever I click nothing happens. Why doesn't it draw a circle? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know almost nothing about pygame so I can't be much more help than this... but what I think you are doing is always drawing back over your circle. Try this out:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

screen.fill((0,0,0))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # draw background first (however)
            screen.fill((0,0,0))

            # draw your other layers (mouse image)

            # draw the circle
            color = (255,255,255)
            posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (posx,posy), 50)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Basically what is happening in your example is that when you mouse down event does a draw, you will then draw back over it again with the background. I am not sure what `mousec` is but that will be drawn over the background every time. So you will never see a circle drawn from your mouse click

My example fills the background once to start, and then when there is a mouse down, it will fill the background again to draw over the previous state, and then draw the circle.

Another approach, using your exact example, is to only record the mouse position when checking the event, and defer the drawing of the circle until after your layers. You would "remember" the last mouse position to constantly redraw that circle on every loop:

```
last_mouse_pos = None

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            last_mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.unicode == 'c':
            # clear the circle when pressing the 'c' key
            last_mouse_pos = None

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mousec.get_width()/2
    y -= mousec.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mousec, (x,y))

    if last_mouse_pos:
        color = (100,100,100)
        posx,posy = last_mouse_pos
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (posx,posy), 50)

    pygame.display.update()
```

The difference in this approach is that you are always drawing everything on each loop as opposed to only in response to changes in events.

**Update**

In response to your question in the comments... a way to modify that second example to retain all the mouse clicks would be to save them up in a `set` and draw them back each time.

```
mouse_clicks = set()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_clicks.add(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.unicode == 'c':
            # clear the circle when pressing the 'c' key
            mouse_clicks.clear()

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mousec.get_width()/2
    y -= mousec.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mousec, (x,y))

    for pos in mouse_clicks:
        color = (100,100,100)
        posx,posy = pos
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (posx,posy), 50)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. Whenever you click again it erases the last circle, do you know how I could make it so all the circles stay?  I imagine I'd have to move screen.blit(background,(0,0)) out of the loop... But I'm not sure :/

Comment: Sure. Just blit the background and the mouse image only once before the loop, so that you are only ever drawing new circles on top. This will work in my first example. The second example would require you to append the positions to a list so that each time you loop you can loop over that list and draw all the circles. The "clear" key could empty the list.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Now the mouse image doesn't move because its out of the loop. I'm going to work on the list right now, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just added an example for you. I used a set. Even though a set is unordered, I figured your circles are solid anyways so order doesn't matter. A set is unique and faster to add new items. So if you click a bunch of times in the exact same spot, its still only one circle.